# Analytic version of Hilbert's XIX problem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

The famous Hilbert's nineteenth problem, initially stated in the $C^\omega$ category, was reduced by Bernstein and Petrowsky to the analogous statement in the $C^\infty$ category (and, after subsequent reductions, was finally solved independently by De Giorgi and Nash), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_nineteenth_problem#The_path_to_the_complete_solution).

> Where can I find a modern treatment of the deduction of the **analytic version** from the smooth one?